# Linux - Install redis-cli only

Tags: linux, redis

I have a Linux server with Redis installed and I want to connect to it via command line from my local Linux machine.

Is it possible to install `redis-cli` only (without `redis-server` and other tools)?

If I just copy `redis-cli` file to my local machine and run it, I have the following error:

```
./redis-cli: /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libc.so.6: version `GLIBC_2.14' not found (required by ./redis-cli)
```

Comment: Well, 1. it is not surprising that just copying the executable does not work: most likely you have different architecture and library versions, that cannot work. 2. you should consult the software management system your distribution provides and see what `redit` packages it provides. Then installing one of those shoudl only require a single click. You should _never_ do a wild installation of stuff into a Linux system if you can use the software management instead.

Comment: @arkascha Thank you for your tip. I'm quite new to Linux so this information is very useful for me

Comment: You mean you are a developer working under a Linux environment, but you never used your systems software management system? What distribution do you use?

Comment: You might also be interested in a package called 'hiredis' which offers a minimalistic c client for redis. No ready-to-use cli client though.

Comment: Well, actually I'm just playing with Redis. I'm on Ubuntu. I've installed Redis and it works fine. Then I installed Debian on VirtualBox, and now I'm trying to connect to Redis on Ubuntu from Debian virtual machine

Comment: So how did you install `redis` on that ubuntu system?

Comment: I've compiled the sources. I can do the same on Debian machine, but I'm just curious can I install just redis-cli without installing all redis components

Comment: it seems that Debian doesn't support neither redis, nor redis-cli packages

Comment: Why invest so much effort? Just pick the redis package in your software management and install it. That takes two minutes most and you can start using it. What is the advantage in doing all that by hand and ignoring all the advantages of cleanly installed packages?

Comment: Debian does not offer redis packages? LOL. One more reasons not to use Debian. (sorry, could not resist).

Comment: https://packages.debian.org/search?keywords=redis-server

Comment: What about `git clone git@github.com:antirez/redis.git` then `cd src && make redis-cli`?

Comment: I recommend the Docker solution, see my answer. Can be disposed at any time and your system's packages are untouched in the process.

Answer (score 544, accepted):

Ubuntu (tested on 14.04) has package called `redis-tools` which contains `redis-cli` among other tools.
To install it type:

```
sudo apt-get install redis-tools
```

Note that on Ubuntu 16.04+ the command is a little bit different:

```
sudo apt install redis-tools
```

Comment: anything similar for centos?

Comment: @AlinPurcaru -  https://gist.github.com/Artistan/d9288f8e12c4027096e66bd331d4e4fd

Comment: @AlinPurcaru docker run --rm --network=host redis redis-cli info

Comment: now it isn't working `http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu bionic-updates/universe amd64 redis-tools amd64 5:4.0.9-1ubuntu0.1` returns 404  Not Found

Answer (score 145):

Instead of `redis-cli` you can simply use `nc`!

```
nc -v --ssl redis.mydomain.com 6380
```

Then submit the commands.

Comment: Try `nc -v redis.mydomain.com 6379` (or your custom port)

Comment: This is the best answer since it requires absolutely no dependencies or external tools.

Comment: is it possible to use this with a redis password?

Comment: You can also use `rlwrap nc -v redis.mydomain.com 6379` if you have `rlwrap` which lets you  use keyboard shortcuts just as you would in a shell (e.g. cycle/search previous command, next word)

Comment: I can't find `--ssl` option for `nc`. Did you mean `ncat`?

Comment: netcat - it depends on your OS what the binary exactly is. maybe it's called ncat. I don't know :(

Comment: @MattBucci You can do the following:

`(printf "AUTH <password> \r\n"; sleep 1) | nc -v redis.mydomain.com 6379`

Comment: This can work, but it's tricky (especially with `--ssl`). There are different versions of `nc` out there -- so this isn't guaranteed to work with your version. The version that supports SSL is [provided by NMAP](https://packages.ubuntu.com/jammy/ncat). To provide a password after connecting, use the command: `AUTH (password)`. Another interesting point is that this works without [installing certificates](https://stackoverflow.com/a/73975504/86967). Hmm.

Answer (score 72):

From http://redis.io/topics/quickstart

```
wget http://download.redis.io/redis-stable.tar.gz
tar xvzf redis-stable.tar.gz
cd redis-stable
make redis-cli
sudo cp src/redis-cli /usr/local/bin/
```

With Docker I normally use https://registry.hub.docker.com/_/redis/. If I need to add redis-cli to an image I use the following snippet.

```
RUN cd /tmp &&\
    curl http://download.redis.io/redis-stable.tar.gz | tar xz &&\
    make -C redis-stable &&\
    cp redis-stable/src/redis-cli /usr/local/bin &&\
    rm -rf /tmp/redis-stable
```

Comment: For enabling SSL in redis-cli Build , I just used  "make BUILD_TLS=yes redis-cli"

Answer (score 39):

In my case, I have to run some more steps to build it on **RedHat** or **Centos**.

```
# get system libraries
sudo yum install -y gcc wget

# get stable version and untar it
wget http://download.redis.io/redis-stable.tar.gz
tar xvzf redis-stable.tar.gz
cd redis-stable

# build dependencies too!
cd deps
make hiredis jemalloc linenoise lua geohash-int
cd ..

# compile it
make

# make it globally accesible
sudo cp src/redis-cli /usr/bin/
```

Comment: Worked for me on Amazon Linux

Comment: Run `make redis-cli BUILD_TLS=yes` instead of only `make` if your server requires SSL

Answer (score 36):

To install [3.0](https://github.com/antirez/redis/tree/3.0) which is the [latest stable version](http://redis.io/download):

```
$ git clone http://github.com/antirez/redis.git 
$ cd redis && git checkout 3.0 
$ make redis-cli
```

Optionally, you can put the compiled executable in your load path for convenience:

```
$ ln -s src/redis-cli /usr/local/bin/redis-cli
```

Comment: `git clone http://github.com/antirez/redis.git && cd redis && git checkout 2.8.6 && make redis-cli && cp src/redis-cli /usr/local/bin` - this works for me.

Comment: tried to edit this. but here is a gist on how to do it now...  https://gist.github.com/Artistan/d9288f8e12c4027096e66bd331d4e4fd

Answer (score 22):

For centOS, maybe can try following steps

```
cd /tmp
wget http://download.redis.io/redis-stable.tar.gz
tar xvzf redis-stable.tar.gz
cd redis-stable
make
cp src/redis-cli /usr/local/bin/
chmod 755 /usr/local/bin/redis-cli
```

Comment: Potentially stupid comment, but don't forget to install gcc `sudo yum install gcc` before running `make`!

Comment: Works on linux too.

Answer (score 19):

Using [Docker](https://www.docker.com/community-edition#/download), you may run this command to get Redis CLI:

```
docker run -it --rm redis:alpine redis-cli -h redis.mycompany.org -p 6379
```

where `redis` is the `redis` docker image from Docker Hub,
`redis-cli` is pre-installed in that image, and all after that are parameters to `redis-cli`:
`-h` is hostname to connect to,
`-p` is apparently the port to connect to.

You could also create an alias using the above command

```
alias redis-cli='docker run -it --rm --network=host redis:alpine redis-cli'
```

Which could be added to `.bashrc` if your using Bash

Comment: Great snippet, I never thought of it ^^

Answer (score 11):

You can also use telnet instead

```
telnet redis-host 6379
```

And then issue the command, for example for monitoring

```
monitor
```

Answer (score 8):

2022 answer:

```
git clone https://github.com/redis/redis.git
cd redis/src/
make redis-cli
sudo cp redis-cli /usr/bin/redis-cli
redis-cli --version
```

worked for me.

Answer (score 7):

For Amazon Linux

```
#sudo amazon-linux-extras install redis6
#redis-cli
```

Answer (score 6):

To expand on @Agis's answer, you can also install the Redis CLI by running

```
$ git clone -b v2.8.7 git@github.com:antirez/redis.git
$ make -C redis install redis-cli /usr/bin
```

This will build the Redis CLI and toss the binary into /usr/bin. To anyone who uses [Docker](https://www.docker.io/), I've also built a Dockerfile that does this for you: https://github.com/bacongobbler/dockerfiles/blob/master/redis-cli/Dockerfile

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I will try it as soon as I can

Comment: For me this command compiled the whole Redis, not only `redis-cli`

Answer (score 5):

If you already have the node environment you can install it with `npm`

`npm i -g redis-cli`

Then run it with

`rdcli`

Answer (score 1):

To install redis 7.2 version, which supports tls, to connect redis database from oracle linux server

```
git clone http://github.com/antirez/redis.git 
cd redis && git checkout 7.2
make redis-cli BUILD_TLS=yes
sudo install -m 755 src/redis-cli /usr/local/bin/

#  on Oracle Linux
redis-cli --tls xyz.redis.me-jeddah-1.oci.oraclecloud.com -p 6379
```

Answer (score 0):

you may scp it from your redis machine if you have one, its just single binary.
Or copy with nc if private network (this method is insecure):

```
redisclient: nc -l 8888 > /usr/local/bin/redis-cli
redisserver: cat /usr/local/bin/redis-cli | nc redisclient 8888
```

Answer (score 0):

There are many way to install `radis-cli`. It comes with `redis-tools` and `redis-server`. Installing any of them will install `redis-cli` too. But it will also install other tools too. As you have `redis-server` installed somewhere and only interested to install `redis-cli`. To install install only `redis-cli` without other unnecessary tools follow below command

```
cd /tmp
wget http://download.redis.io/redis-stable.tar.gz
tar xvzf redis-stable.tar.gz
cd redis-stable
make
cp src/redis-cli /usr/local/bin/
chmod 755 /usr/local/bin/redis-cli
```

Comment: Getting this error on copy command, any idea how to fix it 


cp src/redis-cli /usr/local/bin/
cp: cannot stat 'src/redis-cli': No such file or directory

Answer (score 0):

```
# get system libraries
sudo yum install -y gcc wget

# get stable version and untar it
wget http://download.redis.io/redis-stable.tar.gz
tar xvzf redis-stable.tar.gz
cd redis-stable
make redis-cli
```

If the **build fails** / **make command fails**, then :

> Removing all line with _Atomic from src/server.h and src/networking.c should makes the compile complete.

```
# make it globally accesible
sudo cp src/redis-cli /usr/local/bin/
```

Answer (score 0):

for CentOS to get redis-cli without compiling it you can fetch Redis rpm from Epel repo and extract just ths tool. Here's step by step instruction

```
yum install -y jemalloc
yum install -y yum-utils
# NOTE - EPEL REPO MUST BE INSTALLED AND ENABLED
RPM_URL=$(yumdownloader --urls redis | tail -n1)
RPM=$(basename $RPM_URL)
mkdir /tmp/redis
cd /tmp/redis
wget $RPM_URL
rpm2cpio $RPM | cpio -idmv "./usr/bin/redis-cli"
mv ./usr/bin/redis-cli /usr/bin/redis-cli
rm -rf /tmp/redis
/usr/bin/redis-cli --version
```

Answer (score 0):

**2023 Update**

[Amazon s official documentation for Amazon Linux 2 seems to suggest this](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonElastiCache/latest/red-ug/in-transit-encryption-enable.html)

```
sudo yum -y install openssl-devel gcc
wget http://download.redis.io/redis-stable.tar.gz
tar xvzf redis-stable.tar.gz
cd redis-stable
make distclean
make redis-cli BUILD_TLS=yes
sudo install -m 755 src/redis-cli /usr/local/bin/
```

Answer (score 0):

### 2024 Update

On an Ubuntu based distro, use the following steps:

```
❯ curl -fsSL https://packages.redis.io/gpg | sudo gpg --dearmor -o /usr/share/keyrings/redis-archive-keyring.gpg
❯
❯ echo "deb [signed-by=/usr/share/keyrings/redis-archive-keyring.gpg] https://packages.redis.io/deb $(lsb_release -cs) main" | sudo tee /etc/apt/sources.list.d/redis.list
❯
❯ sudo apt update
❯
❯ sudo apt install redis-tools
❯
```

Answer (score -1):

I made a simple pure-go solution, which is under development.

redis-cli: https://github.com/holys/redis-cli

Build once, and run everywhere. Fully portable.

Please feel free to have a try.

Comment: Liked your solution, the last update is 3 years ago. Did you try building with the new go version, will it make any difference?

Answer (score -2):

There's a script that automatically download, build and install the latest `redis-cli` on Ubuntu 20.04 LTS.

To run it, copy and paste this on your terminal.

```sh
curl -sL "https://raw.githubusercontent.com/SecretX33/redis-cli/main/install_redis_cli.sh" | bash
```

Or `wget`, in case you don't have `curl` installed.

```sh
wget -qO - "https://raw.githubusercontent.com/SecretX33/redis-cli/main/install_redis_cli.sh" | bash
```

Feel free to look the source code: https://github.com/SecretX33/redis-cli

*PS.: I'm the author of this script.*

Comment: Some servers might not accept cURL queries.
The sorts of apps that may be utilized with it may be restricted, which might be pretty problematic.
Automated processes may be exceedingly challenging to employ on servers that do not even support curl.

Comment: This binary can be built once and cached in some internal Nexus server or something among these lines. My script cover the average use-case, which is not install redis-cli on a server, but on a normal workstation for the developer to use.

If for some reason the situation you described happens, I hope the developer responsible for maintaining such servers knows the basics of Linux and Docker to be able to install the redis-cli using this script (either as-is or after some adaptation).